# Find most common value(exclude -1) in numpy 3d array where the corrsponding value in another array is 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays, array_a and array_b, both shape is (2,3,4).

What I want to do is to get the most common value at axis=2 in array_b where the corrsponding value in array_a is 1.

Here is my code. Is there any way to do this faster? Thanks.

```
array_a = np.array([[[-1,-1,-1,1], [-1,-1,-1,1], [-1,1,1,1]], [[-1,-1,1,1], [-1,1,1,1], [-1,1,1,1]]])
array_b = np.array([[[1,2,2,4], [0,0,1,3], [1,1,1,8]], [[0,1,0,3], [3,3,8,8], [3,3,0,1]]])
array_b[array_a!=1] = -1 
    # Only want to use the values in array_b where the corrsponding value in array_a is 1 

result = []
for row in np.ndindex(array_b.shape[:2]):
    count = Counter(array_b[row])
    del count[-1]
    result = np.append(result , count.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Comment: Appending to *result* (not using `np.append`) is ~1.35x faster for small arrays, much faster for larger arrays. `[np.bincount(array_b[row][array_a[row] == 1]).argmax() for row in np.ndindex(array_b.shape[:2])]` is ~3x faster for the included example but memory usage depends on `np.max(array_b)` and will take the smallest element if there are several modes not the first.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks for your answer! It seems my comment disappeared without reason... This one works perfectly for my question, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If I haven't misunderstood the condition of axis = 2; removing the for-loop and using NumPy native selection would improve the performance, if the OP would use a larger dimension array.

```
select = array_b[array_a == 1] # pick all the values in array_b, 
                               # where the corresponding element in 
                               # array_a equals 1

val, cnt = np.unique(select, return_counts=True) # get the frequencies of 
                                                 # values

print( val[np.argmax(cnt)] )  # print the most frequent element.
```

Comment: Given 3 is not the answer OP is after, this is not a valid solution.

Comment: Hi @Julien; that's right. I should have highlighted that removing the for-loop and using NumPy native slicing would be a performance improvement if the OP would use a larger dimension array. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @AliDeğerOzbakir Thanks for you answer! I mainly wanted to know how to do this on a 3-dimension array, so this answer is not quite for my question. The other answer that using "for row in np.ndindex(array_b.shape[:2])]" works well. Still, thank you for your time, also glad to learn the usage of np.unique.